# What is the JSON input format for a Lambda function for proxy integration?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I'm using AWS Lambda with an API Gateway proxy integration (`AWS_PROXY`) such that requests are passed directly without API Gateway imposing any routing.

Lambda is hosting a FastAPI application and Mangum is the intermediary that allows Lambda to respond to requests as a uvivorn server would.

My question is, how should the request be represented as JSON?

```py
@app.get("/get-student/{student_id}")
def get_student(student_id: int):
    return students[student_id]
```

What should an inbound request look like? This is my naive guess. From Mangum documentation, I'm not yet clear on what is required.

```json
{
   "httpMethod":"GET",
   "path":"/get-student/1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lambda proxy integration, API Gateway maps the entire client request to the input `event` parameter of the Lambda function.

This `event` parameter is the **Lambda proxy integration request** and the payload format depends on if you're using version 1 or version 2 of the payload; schemas for both versions are listed in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format).

REST APIs & WebSocket APIs only support sending v1 payloads to Lambda proxy integrations. HTTP APIs support sending both v1 and v2, but via the console, they are configured [by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format) to send the latest version (currently, v2).

*Note to not confuse this with the namespaces that you'd see in the CLI, APIs, CloudFormation, SDKs, or AWS SAM. While the API V1 namespace represents REST APIs & API V2 represents WebSocket and HTTP APIs, the 'namespace versions' do not align with the payload versions.*

For a REST API (v1), a minimal request for your endpoint could look like this:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0", 
  "resource": "/get-student/{student_id}",
  "path": "/get-student/1",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "pathParameters": {
    "student_id": "1"
  }
}
```

And for a HTTP API (v2), a minimal request for your endpoint could look like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "routeKey": "GET /get-student/{student_id}",
  "rawPath": "/get-student/1",
  "pathParameters": {
    "student_id": "1"
  }
}
```

In most AWS SDKs, like the one for .NET, the proxy integration request is available as a class i.e. [`APIGatewayProxyRequest`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs)(v1) / [`APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest.cs) (v2).